# How to apply useIntl language translation in a TypeScript file? Or is there any alternative/preferred workaround?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ant-design-pro

I am current having a quick startup on an Ant Design Pro project, when I try to implement translation with useIntl function from umi, it always give me a **Invalid hook call** error. I tried several workarounds to fix it but failed.

Here are my codes:

**src/pages/user/login/model.ts**

```
import { Effect, history, Reducer, useIntl } from 'umi';
import { message } from 'antd';
import { parse } from 'qs';
import { fakeAccountLogin, getFakeCaptcha } from './service';
import { extend } from 'lodash';

export function getPageQuery() {
  return parse(window.location.href.split('?')[1]);
}

export function setAuthority(authority: string | string[]) {
  const proAuthority = typeof authority === 'string' ? [authority] : authority;
  localStorage.setItem('antd-pro-authority', JSON.stringify(proAuthority));
  // hard code
  // reload Authorized component
  try {
    if ((window as any).reloadAuthorized) {
      (window as any).reloadAuthorized();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // do not need do anything
  }
  
  return authority;
}

export interface StateType {
  status?: 'ok' | 'error';
  type?: string;
  currentAuthority?: 'user' | 'guest' | 'admin';
}

export interface ModelType {
  namespace: string;
  state: StateType;
  effects: {
    login: Effect;
    getCaptcha: Effect;
  };
  reducers: {
    changeLoginStatus: Reducer<StateType>;
  };
}

const Model: ModelType = {
  namespace: 'userAndlogin',
  
  state: {
    status: undefined,
  },
  
  effects: {
    *login({ payload }, { call, put }) {
      const response = yield call(fakeAccountLogin, payload);
      yield put({
        type: 'changeLoginStatus',
        payload: response,
      });
      // Login successfully
      if (response.status === 'ok') {
        const intl = useIntl();
        // Error Here //
        message.success(intl.formatMessage({ id: 'userandlogin.login.success' }));
        const urlParams = new URL(window.location.href);
        const params = getPageQuery();
        let { redirect } = params as { redirect: string };
        if (redirect) {
          const redirectUrlParams = new URL(redirect);
          if (redirectUrlParams.origin === urlParams.origin) {
            redirect = redirect.substr(urlParams.origin.length);
            if (redirect.match(/^\/.*#/)) {
              redirect = redirect.substr(redirect.indexOf('#') + 1);
            }
          } else {
            window.location.href = redirect;
            return;
          }
        }
        history.replace(redirect || '/');
      }
    },

    *getCaptcha({ payload }, { call }) {
      yield call(getFakeCaptcha, payload);
    },
  },

  reducers: {
    changeLoginStatus(state, { payload }) {
      setAuthority(payload.currentAuthority);
      return {
        ...state,
        status: payload.status,
        type: payload.type,
      };
    },
  },
};

export default Model;
```

The error is from the line

```
message.success(intl.formatMessage({ id: 'userandlogin.login.success' }));
```

Initially I thought it might cause by I used the React function in the Typescript file, so I tried to call the message.success in another global service through event, but the same thing happened, so I guess, is that any mistake I made in declaring the const intl in a model response part (maybe not the actual phrase for it, if not understand I can explain further)?

**Edited 1:**

As references, here is the source of the original project.
[Ant Design Pro](https://beta-pro.ant.design/docs/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

**Found Solution**

`getIntl(getLocale()).formatMessage({id:''});`

From: [Github](https://github.com/umijs/umi/issues/5555#issuecomment-712522538)